# Subversion repository killed by revert to revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I´ve already read a few posts about the topic, but no answer for my question.

We have a relativ new repository and my coworkers are working for the first time with a version control system. So their knowledge is non-existent and somebody did a revert that killed the local checkout directory. But slowly:

Person 1 commited new files and had the revision 1048 in branch A (Dev). Branch B (Prod) was at Revision 1009.
Person 2 started the CI system and it failed to build something. This person called Person 1 for help and they had the Idea "Go back to Revsion 1 and let the CI merge the tickets into the branch again."
Via TortoiseSVN they used "Revert to revision" to do exactly that and then, they commited their changes to revision 1049. Deleting thousands of files btw.

Now the working directory on the CI Server, is showing missing files and tree conflicts, of files that are not in the SVN anymore, in the commit window. And of course, it refuses to merge anything while these conflicts remain. 78.000 files reverted to the initial revision was maybe a bit much and I´m stunned myself why they had the idea.

I use the nightly backups to clean this mess. But shouldn´t SVN be able to know, that these files were deleted in the last revision? We updated the cache, deleted the tortoise cache files and nothing worked. But did we trigger a bug like behaviour, because reverting to a prior revision should be possible (not to number 1 though).

Edit: even with new checkouts of the other revisions or copy files from the project from another location into the directory tree didn't solve the issue.

Best regards

Comment: The term "local checkout directory" isn't an official Subversion term but I presume it refers to a "working copy". If that's the case, working copies should be mostly disposable (the versioned information lives on the repository). The easiest fix would be to check out a fresh working copy.

Comment: Yes I mean the working copy. That was also my first idea, we deleted the folder and checked out out fresh from the repository, same problem.

Comment: so when you checked out fresh copy from repository at revision 1049, You were not able to revert back to 1048 to bring back thousands of files?

Comment: No, when we checked out the latest rev 1049, we still had the problem that thousands of files, that are not in branch anymore after the revert and commit, were missing when we opened up the svn commit window from tortoise. 
Then, we dropped it again, checked out 1048 and it was clean, but as soon as we updated to the new rev, the problem came back.

We were thinking of dropping the rev from the svn DB folders, so 1048 is the latest one, but the svn repository directory is on that server, so the admin started the restore, which is faster.